# Animating Android ListView header height causes flicker at the end of animation

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

**Problem**

I'm trying to animate the ListView header height. I can get the animation right, but after the animation completes the ListView flickers.

**Tried and failed**

1. Use `AnimationSet.setFillAfter()` **without** changing the layout params. The animation works fine, but when you start scrolling the list, header jumps back to original position.
2. Use `AnimationSet.setFillAfter()` **with** new layout params applied at `onAnimationEnd()`. After the animation ends the header jumps to twice the required height (animated height plus the height set in layout params). When you start scrolling the list, header snaps to the required height.

**Code**

```
 if (mSearchAdapter.getCount() > 0 && mListView.getChildAt(0) == mHeaderPlaceholder) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Animating list view to make room for info bar");
         AnimationSet slideAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
         TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, newHeight);
         translate.setDuration(mInfoBarAnimationDuration);
         translate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
         slideAnimation.addAnimation(translate);
         slideAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    isAnimatingViewTransition = true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    isAnimatingViewTransition = false;
                    final AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) mHeaderPlaceholder.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = newHeight;
                    mHeaderPlaceholder.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

        });

        mListView.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
 } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "Adjusting list view header to make room for info bar");
        mHeaderPlaceholder.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;

 }
```

I think the flicker can be avoided by listening for and overriding the events `onPreDraw()` or `onGlobalLayout()` of the ViewTreeObserver of the ListView. But I don't know exactly how I can achieve it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of animating ListView header I opted to used ValueAnimator to achieve the same effect. Here is code:

```
if (mSearchAdapter.getCount() > 0 && mListView.getChildAt(0) == mHeaderPlaceholder) {
            ValueAnimator mSlideListViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(from, to);
            mSlideListViewAnimator.setDuration(mInfoBarAnimationDuration);
            mSlideListViewAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            mSlideListViewAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer animatedYValue= (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    final AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) mHeaderPlaceholder.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = animatedYValue;
                    mHeaderPlaceholder.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            mSlideListViewAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    isAnimatingViewTransition = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    isAnimatingViewTransition = false;
                }
            });
            mSlideListViewAnimator.start();
} else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Adjusting list view header to make room for info bar");
            mHeaderPlaceholder.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
}
```